# http://www.www.example.com redirect to https://www.example.com

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have website which is i want to run on `https://www.example.com`, i have set the rule on htaccess file and there i have written following rules.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

After these rules, my website showing on google with `www.example.com` and when i click on `www.example.com` it redirect me `www.www.example.com` 
means www are double time added in the url. I am looking if someone can help me on this part. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are getting double `www` because of your 2nd rules where you are prefixing `www.%{HTTP_HOST}`.

You can have your rules as:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Make sure to use a new browser to test this change.

Comment: Thankyou it works. I just need to sure if I use https://example.com. should it be redirect to https://www.example.com

Comment: `https://example.com/` is already being redirected to `https://www.example.com/` using first rule in question/answer.